# Need to show HTML5 Video Controls on Hover or Play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, controls, html5-video

I'd like to hide the controls for multiple HTML5 videos on a page. If the user hovers over the video the controls should appear. If they click the play button, then the controls should remain visible even if their mouse leaves the video element.

I can't seem to get this to work using the following code. Can anyone spot the problem?

```js
var $video = $('.video');

$video.on('mouseover', show);
$video.on('mouseleave', hide);

function show() {
    $(this).attr('controls', '');
}

function hide() {
    var isPlaying = false;

    this.onplaying = function() {
        isPlaying = true;
    }

    if (!isPlaying) {
        $(this).removeAttr('controls');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video class="video">
    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Instead of setting a the variable `isPlaying`, consider checking the videoElement's `paused` property (`$('.video')[0].paused`), which is `true` when the video hasn't been started yet, is paused (yes, really) or when it has ended. Also, like [K3N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693832/need-to-show-html5-video-controls-on-hover-or-play#answer-48727816) mentioned, the (native) control-bar is handled internally by the browser.

Comment: With the prevalence of touch screens, are you positive that mouseover and mouseleave will work for your audience? Will it be mapped to touchenter / touchleave? If not, your touch based users will not be able to access the video controls.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We cannot really control this behavior as it's managed internally by the browser. All we can do is to specify the `controls` attribute and the browser will do the rest.

For example: in Firefox (v59b when this is written) the controls will fade out when mouse is outside the element when the video is playing even if the `controls` attribute is set - they will show if not playing, kind of the opposite you're after. There is no way to force the controls to stay visible when the user moves the mouse outside the video element.

The only way to properly handle this cross-browser and with exact desired behavior is to build a custom controls UI for the player. This of course means more code is needed to handle the various events so you can update and manage the UI; it may also be a challenge when it comes to platform/browser specific look. But it will on the other hand give you grain control.

An alternative is to look at some libraries which wraps the video element into custom UI controls and see if they allow you to force the controls to stay visible with the given conditions. See for example [videojs](http://videojs.com/) as a starting point.

A small but incomplete example (add functionality, event handlers, design as needed):

```js
var $container = $("#video1");
var $video = $container.children("video"), video = $video[0]
var $controls = $container.children(".controls");
var $play = $controls.children("button");

// control visibility
$container.on("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
  $controls.css("display", e.type === "mouseout" && video.paused ? "none" : "block");
});

// play or pause
$play.on("click", toggle);
$video.on("click", toggle);

function toggle() {
  video[video.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
}

// todo: cover more events (seeked, error etc.)
$video.on("play pause ended", updateUI);

// update control UI elements (todo: update time/progress etc.)
function updateUI() {
  $play.text(video.paused ? "Play" : "Pause")
}
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:0;
  }
.container > .controls {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  padding:7px;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  z-index:10000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=video1 class=container>
  <video width=640 muted src="//media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"></video>
  <div class=controls style="display:none">
    <button>Play</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this code . its working according to your requirements. Use `$('.video').get(0).paused` function in `if` condition to set `isplaying = True`.

```js
var $video = $('.video');

$video.on('mouseover', show);
$video.on('mouseleave', hide);

function show() {
    $(this).attr('controls', '');
}

function hide() {
    var isPlaying = false;
    if(!$('.video').get(0).paused) {
        isPlaying = true;
    }
    if (!isPlaying) {
        $(this).removeAttr('controls');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video class="video">
    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your code and am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paused' of undefined`. I changed `if (!$('.video').get(0).paused) {` to `if (!$(this).get(0).paused) {` and the error went away, but the controls are still disappearing on mouseleave when the video is playing. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I can't get it to play though, since no video is found.

Comment: I just edited your answer and added an open source MP4. Try playing it and note how the controls disappear when the mouse leaves the video element.

Comment: You can just use **this.paused**, because **this == $(this).get(0)**

Answer (score 3):

You can do this pretty easily in any webkit-based browsers. See below for a self-contained example with inline js, including support for keyboard access.

Keeping the controls open during play is the trickiest aspect. It requires CSS pseudo selectors or access to the media player's shadow dom. If you need to support Firefox you may need to look into styling the shadow dom (or creating custom controls).

```css
video[controls]::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: flex !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

/* not required */
video {
    width: 15em;
    height: auto;
}
/* /not required */
```

```html
<video 
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/big-buck-bunny-1080p@0.0.6/video.mp4"
    type="video/mp4"
    onmouseover="dataset.over=true;controls=true"
    onmouseout="delete dataset.over;if(paused) controls=false;"
    onplay="controls=true"
    onpause="if(!dataset.over && !dataset.focus) controls=false"
    onfocusin="dataset.focus=true; controls=true"
    onfocusout="delete dataset.focus; if(paused) controls=false;">
</video>

<video
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/big-buck-bunny-1080p@0.0.6/video.mp4"
    type="video/mp4"
    onmouseover="dataset.over=true;controls=true"
    onmouseout="delete dataset.over;if(paused)controls=false;"
    onplay="controls=true"
    onpause="if(!dataset.over&&!dataset.focus)controls=false"
    onfocusin="dataset.focus=true; controls=true"
    onfocusout="delete dataset.focus;if(paused)controls=false;">
</video>
```

Updating your own code (jQuery, no keyboard/focus considerations):

```js
var $video = $('.video');

$video.on('mouseover', mouseover);
$video.on('mouseout', mouseout);

function mouseover() {
    this.dataset.over = true;
    this.controls = true;
}

function mouseout() {
    delete this.dataset.over;
    if (this.paused)
        this.controls = false;
}
```

```css
video[controls]::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: flex !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

/* not required */
video {
    width: 15em;
    height: auto;
}
/* /not required */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video class="video">
    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And with some very basic custom controls:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.video').forEach($el => {
    let timeout;
    $el.addEventListener('play', () => {
        $el.dataset.playing = '';
    });
    $el.addEventListener('pause', () => {
        delete $el.dataset.playing;
    });
  
    $el.addEventListener('timeupdate', (e) => {
        const $scrub = $el.parentElement.querySelector('.video__scrub');
        const pos = $el.currentTime / $el.duration; 
        const increment = (pos - $scrub.value)/10;
    
        const update = () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            $scrub.value = +$scrub.value + increment;
            if (!$el.paused)
                timeout = setTimeout(update, 50);
        };
        update();
    });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.video__toggle').forEach($el =>
    $el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        $video = $el.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
        $video.paused ? $video.play() : $video.pause();
    }));

document.querySelectorAll('.video__scrub').forEach($el => {
     $el.addEventListener('input', () => {
         const $video = $el.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
         $video.pause();
         $video.currentTime = $el.value * $video.duration;
     });
});
```

```css
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.video__controls {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    padding: 0.2em 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s visibility, 0.2s opacity;
}

.video__wrap:hover .video__controls,
.video[data-playing] ~ .video__controls {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.video__toggle {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
}

.video__toggle::before {
    content: '▶️';
}

.video[data-playing] ~ .video__controls .video__toggle::before {
    content: '⏸';
}

.video__scrub {
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    margin: 0;
}

/* not required */
.video__wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    height: 56.25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video__wrap">
    <video class="video" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/big-buck-bunny-1080p@0.0.6/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <nav class="video__controls">
        <button class="video__toggle"></button>
        <input class="video__scrub" type="range" min=0 max=1 value=0 step=0.001>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="video__wrap">
    <video class="video" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/big-buck-bunny-1080p@0.0.6/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <nav class="video__controls">
        <button class="video__toggle"></button>
        <input class="video__scrub" type="range" min=0 max=1 value=0 step=0.001>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: the `video[controls]::-webkit-media-controls-pane` css just fixed a huge problem for me with controls not showing up in chrome for some reason. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Attribute `controls` is boolean:

```
// by id video.
document.getElementById("video1").controls = true; //show
document.getElementById("video1").controls = false; //hide.

//or all video by tag name:
document.getElementsByTagName("video").controls = true; //show
document.getElementsByTagName("video").controls = false; //hide.
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you set on the `onplaying` handler, you're still setting `isPlaying` to be false everytime the `show()` is executed so it will always remove the controls.  Try changing your logic a bit.  Like handle when the video stops, pauses, or otherwise changes state.  Use those to change your logic in showing the controls.

Answer (score 1):

## Updated - The only Cross-browser Solution is Custom Controls

**Chrome and Firefox controls are visible on hover and playback. As a side bonus it is responsive. Note: If you want to see it function properly for Firefox and Chrome in fullscreen, see the [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/iYC4CopRqnHBwjTqVxkR/)**.

It looks as if it's not entirely feasible to show controls when playing video unless the mousemove event is fired. At first I figured that if one could move the mouse 1px back and forth then that'd be the solution albeit hacky and resource consuming. Unfortunately moving the mouse cursor programmatically is impossible because no one really appreciates their mouse being hijacked no matter how innocent a developer's intentions are.

At first I thought `.focus()` would work, but not for Firefox, so after trying to find a solution for a simple cross-browser behavior, it came down to removing the controls entirely and creating custom controls. It involves a ton of special styles that are specific to each browser. See this article: [**Creating a Custom HTML5 Video Player and the Shadow DOM**](https://blog.hellojs.org/creating-a-custom-html5-video-player-and-the-shadow-dom-a98f29261be4). The following demo is a multiple player jQuery version of the article's [demo](https://interglobalmedia.github.io/custom-html5-video-player/). For details and references see [**README.md**](https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cjdso0co90006fill518inlvx/README.html).

[**Plunker**](https://embed.plnkr.co/iYC4CopRqnHBwjTqVxkR/)

#### Demo - Custom Controls - Note: Firefox and Chrome in full screen mode see [**Plunker**](https://embed.plnkr.co/iYC4CopRqnHBwjTqVxkR/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <style>
  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
  body {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(135def, #7c1599 0%, #921099 48%, #7e4ae8 100%);
    background-size: cover;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .cover {
    max-width: 750px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .video {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .toggle {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 50px;
  }
  
  .toggle:focus {
    border-color: #ffc600;
  }
  
  .volume {
    width: 10px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .panel {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(100%) translateY(-5px);
    transition: all 0.3s;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 2147483648;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .cover:hover .panel,
  .panel.active {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .panel:hover .progress,
  .panel.active .progress {
    height: 15px;
  }
  
  .panel > * {
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .progress {
    flex: 10;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: ew-resize;
  }
  
  .bar {
    width: 50%;
    background: #ffc600;
    flex: 0;
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  /* unholy css to style input type="range" */
  
  input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 12px 3px;
  }
  
  input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-radius: 1.3px;
    border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  }
  
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #ffc600;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  
  input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ffc600;
  }
  
  input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 1.3px;
    border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  }
  
  input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 0px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #ffc600;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /* full screen button styling */
  
  .fullscreen {
    margin-right: 7px;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 30px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  /* Because video needed a defined hieght in order for object-fit: fill to work. */
  
  video {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
  }
  /* hide the default Chrome video player styling */
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-enclosure {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none !important;
  }
  /*  Needed to hide player controls in Safari Only */
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
    display: none !important;
  }
  /* Firefox Shadow DOM Fix */
  
  *::-moz-list-bullet,
  *::-moz-list-number {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  *::-moz-meter-bar {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  :-moz-full-screen:not(:root)::backdrop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  *::backdrop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  :fullscreen:not(:root) {
    display: none !important;
  }
  /* New addition to removal of User Agent StyleSheet for Firefox. Removed dotted border around range. */
  
  input[type="range"]::-moz-focus-outer {
    border: 0;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id='V0' class='cover'></div>

  <div id='V1' class='cover'></div>

  <div id='V2' class='cover'></div>

  <div id='V3' class='cover'></div>

  <template id='controls'>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="toggle" title="Play/Pause">
        <i class="fa fa-play fa-3x"></i>
      </button>
      <input type="range" class="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="0.70">
      <button class='fullscreen'>
        <i class='fa fa-expand fa-2x'></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
  <script>
var mp4 = ['005609.mp4', '005610.mp4', '005611.mp4', '005612.mp4'];
var webm = ['041157.mp4', '041153.mp4', '041154.mp4', '041156.mp4'];

function init(VMp4, VWebm) {

  var VArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cover'));

  VArray.map(function(V, idx) {
    var ID = V.id;
    return players(ID, idx, VMp4, VWebm);
  });
}

function players(id, IDX, vMp4, vWebm) {

  var V = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(V);

  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var tag = document.createElement('video');
  var src0 = document.createElement('source');
  var src1 = document.createElement('source');

  tag.classList.add('video');
  tag.controls = false;
  tag.width = '320';
  tag.style.background = '#000';
  tag.poster = `https://gincore.net/images/video-play-2.png`;
  // Set Paths
  var mUrl = `https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/`;
  var wUrl = `https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20180214/`;
  src0.type = 'video/mp4';
  src1.type = 'video/webm';
  src0.src = mUrl + vMp4[IDX];
  src1.src = wUrl + vWebm[IDX];

  frag.appendChild(tag);
  tag.appendChild(src0);
  tag.appendChild(src1);

  V.appendChild(frag);

  var controls = document.querySelector('#controls').content;
  var clone = document.importNode(controls, true);
  V.appendChild(clone);
}

init(mp4, webm);


$(".cover").each(function() {
  
  var C = $(this)[0].id;
  
  var $ctl = $(this).find('.panel');
  var $vid = $(this).find('.video');
  var $tog = $(this).find('.toggle');
  var $prg = $(this).find('.progress');
  var $bar = $(this).find('.bar');
  var $vol = $(this).find('.volume');
  var $tfs = $(this).find('.fullscreen')

  var ctl = $ctl[0];
  var vid = $vid[0];
  var tog = $tog[0];
  var prg = $prg[0];
  var bar = $bar[0];
  var vol = $vol[0];
  var tfs = $tfs[0];

  function togglePlay() {
    var playPause = vid.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
    vid[playPause]();
    $tog.find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause');
  }

  function updateVolume() {
    vid.volume = this.value;
  }

  function updateProgress() {
    var perc = (vid.currentTime / vid.duration) * 100;
    bar.style.flexBasis = `${perc}%`;
  }

  function seekTrack(e) {
    var seekTime = (e.offsetX / prg.offsetWidth) * vid.duration;
    vid.currentTime = seekTime;
  }

  var isFullScreen = function() {
    return !!(document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.fullscreenElement);
  };

  function toggleFS() {
    if (!isFullScreen()) {
      if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
        vid.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        vid.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (document.getElementById(C).mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.getElementById(C).mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (vid.msRequestFullscreen) {
        vid.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
      $tfs.find('.fa').removeClass('fa-expand').addClass('fa-compress');
      $ctl.removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').css('z-index', '-1');
      $('#' + C + " .panel").css('z-index',"2147483648");
    } else {
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.msCancelFullscreen) {
        document.msCancelFullscreen();
      }
      $tfs.find('.fa').addClass('fa-expand').removeClass('fa-compress');
      if (!vid.pause || !vid.ended) {
        $ctl.addClass('active');
      }
      $('.panel').css('z-index', '2147483648');
    }
  }

  function go() {
    $ctl.addClass('active');
    $tog.find('.fa').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
  }

  function stop() {
    $ctl.removeClass('active');
    $tog.find('.fa').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
  }

  $vid.on('click', togglePlay);

  $tog.on('click', togglePlay);

  $vid.on('timeupdate', updateProgress);

  $vid.on('playing', go);

  $vid.on('ended pause', stop);

  $vol.on('input', updateVolume);

  var mousedown = false;

  $prg.on('click', seekTrack);

  $prg.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousedown && seekTrack(e);
  });

  $prg.on('mousedown', function() {
    mousedown = true;
  });

  $prg.on('mouseup', function() {
    mousedown = false;
  });

  $tfs.on('click', toggleFS);

});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If it still doesn't work then copy and paste then entire code on any text editor and save it with an `.html` extension then open that file in Firefox and/or Chrome. That'll work 100%.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm unable to [reproduce in Firefox v59b/60a](https://imgur.com/a/uNyWt) (Windows, no add-ons). What version are you using?

Comment: @K3N my bad, see update for the only cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SwiftShard/fg9tjque/).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video class=video>

    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<style>

    video[controls]::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
        display:flex!important;
        opacity:1!important
    }
</style>

<script>

    var $video=$(".video");
    $video.on("mouseover",function() {
        this.dataset.over = true;
        this.controls = true;
    }),
    $video.on("mouseout",function() {
        this.dataset.over = false;
        if (this.paused)
            this.controls = false;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Checkout the existing answers before answering to see if you are suggesting anything new

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    video::-webkit-media-controls {
        opacity: 0
    }
    video::-webkit-media-controls:hover {
        opacity: 1
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please format your code into a readable format. Also, explain your code. What does it do?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25985096)